# Bash construct to extract the two values from commands like:"--option=false"?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Does anyone know the bash construct where you specify the delimeter and you get in two variables ( $@ or $! or something like that I think ) the values?

For example:
--option=false should be specified with '=' delimeter and in one variable there will be the word 'option' whereas in the other variable the word 'false' is stored. Anyone know?

P.S.: No sed, awk or IFS solutions please. I am aware of them but I am requesting the specific bash construct :)

Comment: If you split "--option=false" on =, wouldn't the first variable then hold "--option", not just "option"? Otherwise there seems to be extra option-aware intelligence going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found in the Bash man page, you can use Parameter Expansion to solve your problems.

```
# split first argument on equal sign (left=right)    
left=${1%%=*}
right=${1#*=}
```

Comment: Thanks! It was exactly what I was looking for! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the *GNU getopt* program is appropriate here (if available, of course).
It supports long options.